# Find a $x$ such that $2^{2015}x\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Since 13 is prime number using little Fermat's theorem $2^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ then $2^{2015}\equiv 2^{12\cdot167+11}\equiv 2^{11} \pmod{13}$ then $2^{2015} x \equiv 2^{11} x \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ so then $x\equiv 2$, is this ok?

Comment: There is no $x$ in $2^{2015}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. Given that $2^{2015}\equiv7\pmod{13}$, there is no such $x$ at all.

Comment: So you mean "Find"?  or are we expected to "Wind" $x$ about something?  or is it just windy where you are?

Comment: I think the OP meant to say find $x$ such that $2^{2015} x \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$.

Comment: sorry I did not saw that I write wind

Comment: To check that $x=2$ works is the same as checking $2^{2016}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$, but that follows from the fact that $12\,|\,2016$.

Comment: Yes, you have correctly deduced that $\,x\equiv 2\,$ is a solution.  But you should give more details in the inference "so then $x\equiv 2$"

Comment: No it's not okay. You only get partial credit, because your "so then x ≡ 2" seems to have just blown by on the wind... Nobody knows where it came from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By  Fermat's theorem,
     $$2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$
Observe that, ${12}\mid {2016}$
Therefore, $$ 2^{2016}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$
Which is same as $$2^{2015}\times 2\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$
So $x= 2$ is a solution of the congruence.

Comment: Also note that $2^{2015}\equiv 7\pmod{13}$ . So the above congruence is equivalent to $7x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ ,which is a linear congruence and easier to solve.

Comment: You should write "so $x\equiv 2$ is a solution of the congruence". Otherwise it is not clear which direction "so" denotes (clarity is essential here since often necessary and sufficient conditions are mixed up).